# MULE 3.8.1 Hibernate 4.3.11 - org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile

Tags: spring, hibernate, mule-esb

I am developing an application for MULE ESB CommunityEdition (3.8.1 version).

I have included (provided by MULE) SPRING 4.1.6.RELEASE in project.

For persistence layer I set up Hibernate 4.3.11.FINAL.

My code is based on this idea (https://www.ricston.com/blog/jpa-mule/).

So basically i have included in the project (besides MULE dependencies):

- hibernate-entitymanager (4.3.11.Final)
- hibernate-core  (4.3.11.Final)
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api (1.0.0.Final)
- spring-orm  (4.1.6.RELEASE)

And everything was working perfectly fine until i started to use Java 8 API...

Whatever I do: any lambda, stream or anything I am still getting error:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
```

What I did until now:

- tried to add org.javassist dependency (in version from 3.18.0-GA to 3-22.0-GA) - nothing happened,
- tried to exclude org.reflections.0.9.9 dependency (mule is including that in some its core dependencies): also nothing happened

I spent on this about 5 hours I am really close to give it up... I really need hibernate cause this project will include many db operations

What else Can i Try to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!!
I was using `mvn dependency:tree` to check if there are any `org.javassist` dependencies in project.
And there weren't...

Then I checked the folder: `{mule_home}/lib/opt` and there was an old version of `org.javassist` library!

So: I downloaded latest `org.javassist` jar and I put it in the `{mule_home}/lib/user` folder.
Now it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your Anypoint Studio is pointing correct JDK.

Check below

> Preference> Installed JRE >> It should have JDK 1.8 checked.

Comment: Hi,
I am using Intellij IDEA plugin to develop mule applicaitons.
But of course: in project settings i have choosen JDK 1.8.